# Integral involved in arcsine law

Tags: probability, integration

I'm making some sort of silly mistake in doing the integral at the final step of showing the arcsine law for discrete random walks.  I am supposed to get

$$\int^{xn}_0 \frac{du}{\pi\sqrt{u(n-u)}}=\frac2\pi\sin^{-1}\sqrt x $$

but can't.  What I have is

$$\int^{xn}_0 \frac{du}{\pi\sqrt{u(n-u)}}=\\
\frac1\pi\int^{xn}_0 \frac{du}{\sqrt{n^2/4-(u-n/2)^2}}=\\
\frac1\pi\int^{xn-n/2}_{-n/2}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{n^2/4-(y)^2}}=\\
\frac1\pi\sin^{-1}\left.\left(\frac{y}{n/2}\right)\right|^{xn-n/2}_{-n/2}=\\
\frac1\pi\left(\sin^{-1}(2x-1)-\sin^{-1}(-1)\right)=\\
\frac1\pi\sin^{-1}(2x-1)+1/2$$

I'd greatly appreciate being set right.

Comment: you will Need the Euler Substitution , see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution